# Does app run just a little bit slower when testing on device from xcode? (made in unity)

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I made an app in unity and used Unity remote to test it and make it. The problem is when i pressed play and tested in unity the gameobjects with transform.translate moved a certain speed but when i rendered out an APK and tested on my andriod phone all of the sudden those same objects moved at like double the speed.  Now i calibrated the difficulty of the game by following the speed on my phone thinking thats what the end gameplay will be like.

I was fine with this until i tried uploading the app to IOS.  Now in xcode when i press play and try to test it on my iphone the app automatically installs on my phone and starts playing. (I am not sure how this system exactly works). So now those same gameobjects move at the speed that was previously shown in the Unity editor.

I am not sure which speed is the true speed.  Are my andriod apps gonna move at the speed they moved on my andriod phone while i tested and the ios ones run at the speed they ran at which they did through xcode? or is xcode just being weird and the actual Game will run the same speed as it does on my andriod phone when i properly publish the apk and test on my andriod phone.

Comment: Are you using [`Time.deltaTime`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) in your speed/movement calculations?

Comment: just noticed that i didnt use it there, should i add it?

This is how i moved them:
transform.Translate( new Vector3(dir2, -dir, 0), Space.World);